# How to delete an object from state when it is inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, javascript-objects

I'm trying to delete an object from an array within an object by the id. I can't figure out how to do this...I've looked at several other posts but I feel like the set up is a little different so I still can't figure it out.

`deleteMeals` doesn't delete the correct object even though I am grabbing the correct meal id. The "Monday" is also there as a placeholder / trying to figure things out.

I had my `store` set up differently before, where each meal object had its own `day` key, and I was able to delete - except the first object (id: 1) would not delete until it was the last one. I ended up refactoring the store so that each meal object was in an array separated by the actual Day.

So now I need help with two issues please!

1. How to properly delete given my store object set up
2. Why the proper meal won't delete

```
    const store = {
    
       meals: {
            "Monday": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "recipe_id": 2,
                     "user_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "recipe_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "recipe_id": 3,
                    "user_id": 1
                }
    
            ],
            "Tuesday": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "recipe_id": 4,
                    "user_id": 1
                }
            ],
            "Wednesday": [],
        }
   }
```

deleteMeal in App.js

```
deleteMeal = (day, mealId) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
  // copy existing state
  ...prevState,
  // update meals key
  meals: {
      // copy existing meals state
      ...prevState.meals,
     // update day key & filter meals array by id
     [day]: prevState.meals[day].filter( ({ id }) => id !== mealId),
  }
 }));
}

const contextValue = {
            recipes: this.state.recipes,
            meals: this.state.meals,
            addRecipe: this.addRecipe,
            deleteRecipe: this.deleteRecipe,
            updateRecipe: this.updateRecipe,
            addMeal: this.addMeal,
            deleteMeal: this.deleteMeal
        }
```

Days Component

```
class Days extends React.Component{
    render() {
        const { day, meals } = this.props
        let mealsList;

        if (meals[day]) {
            mealsList = meals[day]
                .map((meal, key) => 
                    <Meals 
                        key={key}
                        day={day}
                        meal={meal}
                    />
            )
        }
        
        return(
            <div className="Days">
                <h3>{day}</h3>
                {meals && meals[day] && mealsList}
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

Meals Component

```
class Meals extends React.Component {
    static contextType = StashContext;

    state = {
        recipeTitle: 'No Title',
        recipeImageUrl: '',
        showModal: false
    }

    findRecipe = (recipeId, recipes) => {
        const recipe = recipes.find( recipe => recipe.id == recipeId)

        if (recipe) {
            this.setState({
                recipeTitle: recipe.title,
                recipeImageUrl: recipe.image_url
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { recipes } = this.context
        const { meal } = this.props

        this.findRecipe(meal.recipe_id, recipes)
    }

    handleClickDelete = (event) => {
        const { day, meal } = this.props
        const { id } = meal
        event.preventDefault()
        this.context.deleteMeal(day, id)
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            showModal: !this.state.showModal
        })
    }

    render(){
        const { recipeTitle, recipeImageUrl, showModal } = this.state;
        const { meal } = this.props;

        const customStyles = {
            overlay: {
                background: '#4c645682'
            },
            content: {
                background: 'rgb(240 240 240)'
            }
        }

        const permissions = {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            delete: false
        }

        return (
            <div className="Meals">
                {showModal && 
                    <DisplayModal 
                        meal={meal} 
                        customStyles={customStyles} 
                        showModal={showModal}
                        closeModal={this.toggleModal}
                        label="Meal Modal"
                        permissions={permissions}
                    />
                }

                <div className="Meals__info">
                    <div className="info_box left">
                        <div className="Meals__img">
                            <img src={recipeImageUrl} alt="Placeholder" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="info_box middle">
                        <div className="Meals__recipe-title">
                            {recipeTitle}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info_box right">
                        <div className="Meals__options">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faEye} 
                                onClick={e => {this.setState({showModal: true})}} />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon 
                                icon={faBackspace} 
                                onClick={this.handleClickDelete} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Meals
```

Comment: Why do you need both the meal and recipe ids? Can two elements in a day have the same meal id?

Comment: I think I've answered (2) but for (1) I think we'd need more context in how your store relates to your UI (i.e. components), presumably related to the delete function, though it isn't clear why it seems you may have two sources of truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe id appears to be extraneous, I don't think it is needed, you should be able to delete a meal by day and id.

The idea is to shallowly copy the state object at *each level* you intend to update.

```
deleteMeal = (day, mealId) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    // copy existing state
    ...prevState,
    // update meals key
    meals: {
      // copy existing meals state
      ...prevState.meals,
      // update day key & filter meals array by id
      [day]: prevState.meals[day].filter(({ id }) => id !== mealId),
    },
  }));
}
```

## Issue - Poor React Key

You are using the array index as the react key in your `Days` component.

```
meals[day].map((meal, key) => (
  <Meals 
    key={key} // <-- array index!!
    day={day}
    meal={meal}
  />
))
```

If you for example had an array of three meals and you delete the first or second, the react keys would still be index 0 and 1. The length would change and the 3rd meal would no longer be rendered, but because the react key for the first two didn't change react bails on rerendering them.

[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
> change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
> with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
> [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
> key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

The important take-away from the linked article is this checklist

> 1. the list and items are static–they are not computed and do not change;
> 2. the items in the list have no ids;
> 3. the list is never reordered or filtered.
>
> When *all* of them are met, you **may safely use the index as a key**.

Array indices *are* technically acceptable as react keys, so long as you ***don't*** mutate the array by inserting or deleting elements from it. Since your `meal` objects have an `id` property it should be used for the react key.

```
meals[day].map(meal => (
  <Meals 
    key={meal.id}
    day={day}
    meal={meal}
  />
))
```

Comment: hmm I'll have to look more into prevState as i haven't used that before.
To answer your other comment about the recipeId --- I left the recipe object out of the store because I think it might not be irrelevant to deleting the meal? It is just an id to reference the recipe for the meal (for displaying it)

With your solution, I can delete the meal object...but its still not deleting the correct one.

Comment: I just discovered that no matter which meal I click to delete, it will delete the last one first of the day.  So for Monday meals, if I click meal id 1, it will delete id 3, then 2, and then 1

Comment: @staysee Maybe the handler isn't being passed the correct values. Can you update your question to include your component code and how you are mapping your UI and attaching `deleteMeal` as a handler?

Comment: Hi Drew, I just updated my question with my Meals component!

Comment: @staysee Am I reading this correctly, the `Meals` component renders only a single meal object? `deleteMeal` (`this.context.deleteMeal`) is invoked in `handleClickDelete` via `this.props.day` and `this.props.meal.id`? Have you logged the meal id there in the handler to ensure it is the one you want? Then log it again in `deleteMeal`? Can you share the context code? There may be something goofy with how you delete there.

Comment: I've updated with my Days component that renders each individual Meals (I should probably update the name to just Meal)....and provided the deleteMeal that I'm passing into my context

Comment: @staysee Ah, I think I see the issue now. Your `Days` component uses an array index as the react key for array data you are deleting. Updating my answer.